# Marcar uma resposta como útil

Tags: debate, votos

Marcar *"Esta resposta é útil"* sem testar de fato o que foi dito, mas marcar pelo esforço de pesquisa e por responder.

É válido? ou errado?

Comment: Útil é o voto positivo. Se você tem grande chance de concordar com a utilidade da resposta (mesmo que porventura tenha erros de sintaxe no código ou um deslize eventual nos conceitos), então creio que seja válido. A questão do que é "útil" e o que é "utilidade" creio que não caiba em um comentário. Claro, eventuais discordâncias e erros devem ser pelo menos mencionados nos comentários para tornar claro e tentar aumentar a utilidade da resposta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upvote ("Esta resposta é útil") é direito seu, mas o objetivo é apontar aquilo que é útil, esforço pode ser também retribuído com upvote se desejar, ainda sim seria mais interessante se testasse, pois os upvotes costumam iludir futuros visitantes que tem o mesmo problema.

Ao fazer isto você estará indicando para outros usuários e futuros usuários que aquilo funciona e poderá na verdade causar problemas para terceiros que você nem imagina acaso na verdade a resposta esteja errada.

Creio que o ideal, seja sempre testar e ter paciência, não existe tempo para dar upvote, você pode esperar o tempo que quiser, o mesmo vale para marcar como aceita, não é obrigado a marcar nada só porque "parece" a correta, testar é sempre bom.

Não deixe a impaciência de alguns autores de respostas que exigem/cobram upvotes ou voto de aceitação lhe pressionarem, você tem o direito de votar se quiser ou não, a escolha é sua, claro que se puder buscar o ideal que é votar em algo que foi testado, pois assim como uma resposta irá ajudar futuros visitantes, o seu upvote irá qualificar se aquela resposta é a ideal ou é uma boa solução.

Answer (score 2):

> *Marcar pelo esforço de pesquisa*

Acho válido, mesmo que contenha algum problema menor (pode-se inquirir o AR sobre os problemas para melhorar a resposta). Às vezes é fácil perceber quando uma resposta foi ***de fato*** trabalhada (um indício -- apenas um indício -- é a diferença entre o tempo da pergunta e o da resposta). Acho válido valorizar o esforço do AR quando a resposta mostra não só o esforço, mas algo útil (como propõe o *tooltip* da seta *upvote*).

> *Marcar por responder*

Isso é bem relativo. Apenas o fato de ter respondido não é fator determinante para marcar como útil. O que importa é o teor da resposta, se é de fato útil. É comum APs darem *upvotes* a todas respostas recebidas como se fosse um *prêmio* apenas por terem respondido. Eu acho isso errado, mas o voto é algo individual e não se pode ter controle sobre isso. Bem como o AP pode marcar ✓ uma resposta bem pior do que outras. Como sabemos: *nem sempre a melhor resposta é a marcada com ✓*.

---

Portanto, se é *válido* ou *errado*, pode ser uma coisa ou outra. O certo é não *marcar por marcar*. Marcar uma resposta sem uma análise ou testar se funciona é dizer que o AR fornece "boas respostas" e caso haja erros na resposta, irá influenciar outros usuários de forma negativa.